# Getting Error while consuming self created webservices which connect Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: web-services

I am creating a webservices and while consuming getting error like this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: >Mapping qname not fond for the package: oracle.jdbc.driver
>     at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse>>>>(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
>     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>     at com.db.DatabaseClassStub.getDataBaseConnection(DatabaseClassStub.java:185)
>     at com.db.TestDatabaseClass.main(TestDatabaseClass.java:13)

For creating webservices that Connect Oracle SQL Developer using apache axis2 and eclipse. I have used the following s/w:
1). Eclipse Helios
2). Apache Tomcat 6
3). axis2-1.6.1-bin and axis2-1.6.1-war and also kept "ojdbc5" in tomcat lib folder.

My Webservices creation java code is,

```
package com.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseClass {
    static Connection con = null;
    public static Connection getDataBaseConnection()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {       
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.137.12.133:1521:ora11gr2","tran1","training123");           

        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }

        return con;     
    }
}
```

and Consuming webservices Java code is:

```
package com.db;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import com.db.DatabaseClassStub.GetDataBaseConnection;
import com.db.DatabaseClassStub.GetDataBaseConnectionResponse;

public class TestDatabaseClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        DatabaseClassStub stub = new DatabaseClassStub();
        GetDataBaseConnection conn = new GetDataBaseConnection();
        GetDataBaseConnectionResponse response = stub.getDataBaseConnection(conn);
        System.out.println(response.get_return());
    }

}
```

will you plz let me know where i am doing wrong?whenever i trying to execute TestDatabaseClass.java getting error which i have mentioned earlier. Same code (DatabaseClass.java) when i am executing in simple java project, its giving output but why not in webservices ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'export' a JDBC `Connection` in a SOAP web service operation: what goes across the wire has to be by definition serializable (as an XML).

You can expose methods/operations that provide the results of a query.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Means you are saying that database connection object is created seperately and then make querry on them and then result is to be exposed in some methods.If i am right then  regarding this I have some questions. In which class i will create database connection object and make querry according to the requirement.plz reply and once again thanks 2 you.

Comment: I suggest you design a Web Service layer which exposes methods/operations to be used as SOAP Web Services. This WS Layer 'talks' to a DAO Layer which handles all the Database operations. In other words, you isolate the Web Services calls from the Database calls so that a re-design of one has a minimal impact on the other one (it also facilitates user/role/permissions management)

Comment: Very thankful 2 u. Actually i very new in webservices. Will u plz provide some sample code or any link that implements this one.